# deploy.last in JBoss 5.1 in web configuration?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

We have ear that depends on war file.
We use web configuration.
I put war file to `<jboss_home>/server/web/deploy` directory.
And I put ear file to `<jboss_home>/server/web/deploy/deploy.last` directory.
But ear starts prior to war.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar configuration to what you describe, though I put all the apps I want to deploy first in `deploy/myapps` and all the ones to deploy afterwards in `deploy/myapps.last`. This works correctly for me on JBoss 5.1.2.

Although I can't explain why it isn't working for you, I can offer an alternative solution. You can make the EAR declare a dependency on the WAR and JBoss will then ensure the WAR is deployed first.

First, add a file called `aliases.txt` into the `META-INF` directory of your WAR. This file should just contain a single line with an arbitrary name / identifier for your WAR. For example, if you have mywebapp.war, your `META-INF/aliases.txt` file could contain 'mywebapp'. It just needs to be something that won't clash with any other aliases declared by other apps deployed on the same server.

Next, add a `jboss-dependency.xml` file to the `META-INF` directory of your EAR, containing the following (subsituting 'mywebapp' for the alias you created above):

```
<dependency xmlns="urn:jboss:dependency:1.0">
  <item whenRequired="Real" dependentState="Create">mywebapp</item>
</dependency>
```

This should ensure the WAR is deployed before the EAR.

Also, if you try to deploy the EAR without the WAR being present, JBoss will log a clear deployment error message telling you about the missing dependency.